# destructuring external modules in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Will Typescript's destructuring feature support code like this?

```
import {each, map} = require('underscore');
```

It doesn't appear to work with the latest code in the master branch even though other desctructuring code compiles. For example,

```
var o = {x:1, y:1};
var {x, y} = o;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work for `var {each, map} = require('underscore');` It might not be implemented for `import` yet. Reported here : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/240

Answer (score 0):

Actually **`import _ = require('underscore');`** is like **`import * as _ from require('underscore');`**
So you can't destructure it in import statement. You can do it in below way:

```
import _ = require('underscore');
const {each, map} = require('underscore');
```